# In KendoUI I do not understand the "Mobile Widgets"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Eg on this page http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui, Telerik have ListView under Data management and also ListView under Mobile Widgets.

Are they saying the when a responsive webpage is being viewed using say an iPhone then the "ListView under Mobile Widgets" will be used and when the SAME website is viewed on a desktop then the "ListView under Data management" will be used.

If so then do 2 ListViews have to be defined on the same webpage.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to define two ListViews. The mobile view will be automatically applied when viewing on mobile and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a contact who knows someone at Telerik and his reply is...

Yes, it's a bit confusing. They really have two widgets but one of them is for **native mobile application development only**. And the whole KendoUI Mobile suite is tailored to meet the needs of developers who make native mobile applications. The answer you got in stackoverlow is essentially incorrect - yes, the mobile ListView will render on desktop browsers but will think that those are mobile browsers and I can already see many problems coming up as a result. Furthermore, do note how the mobile suite lacks the heavier controls from its web counterpart - there is no mobile grid, no mobile editor, date pickers, combos etc., because it is very difficult to create them so that they run on all mobile platforms and if the Kendo team intends to develop them at all some day it will take years.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to specify auto mode in the list view definition of yours. So when the the list is being viewed in the mobile it will automatically render the mobile widget ui instead of normal kendo ui. Please see below:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model)
               ...............
               .Mobile(MobileMode.Auto)
```

Here you have the option to set different MobileMode: 1. Auto 2. Phone 3. Tablet 4. Disabled